# How to start a Symfony server with environment variables from .env.test?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Is there any way to start the build in server with environment variables like `DATABASE_URL` from other environments like `.env.test` instead of `.env`?

I want to use diffrent databases for dev and test but the Symfony server allways starts using dev.

I already tried stuff like:

```
APP_ENV=test bin/console server:start
```

Im using symfony4

Comment: bin/console --env=test server:start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `/bin/console` you will see little help for this command and there you should see following flag:

```
-e, --env=ENV         The Environment name. [default: "dev"]
```

It means you can simply run `bin/console --env=test server:start`.

Comment: This works! Now the app is using the variables provided in the .env.test file as I wanted but for some reason some features stopped working when I start the app in test env. For example the login fails without any errormessages.

Comment: You have to be aware that there are usually three environments (test/dev/prod) and each load different yaml files - so maybe some services are not registered? Take a look into var/test.log, there should be something interesting.

Comment: Thank you will definetly do

Answer (score 0):

You need to change .env file to change environement from dev to prod, so i think the best way is make two files :

First one for local with dev configuration and another one in prod server with another configuration.

You can also configure your database in config/packages/doctrine.yaml like this :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        dbname:               ****
        host:                 127.0.0.1
        port:                 8889
        user:                 ****
        password:             ****
```

Hope this help.